# MYSQL unable to load OR operator on different tables

Tags: php, mysql, query-performance

I think nothing wrong with my query, but don't know why system becomes very slow when I load this code in phpmyadmin. Any advice please help.

```
select
  *
from
  `table1`
left join
   `table2`
on
  table1.id = table2.id
where
(
   (table1.email = 'test@test.com' and table1.mobile = '99999999')
 or
   (table2.email = 'test@test.com' and table2.mobile = '99999999')
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the `like` operators? Use `=`

Comment: Try sticking `EXPLAIN` in front of the query and running it... MySQL itself can actually provide you with a basic performance report.

Comment: How many records in the table? Any indexes on the fields in question?

Comment: Sounds like table1 and table2 could be normalised into something more useful.

Comment: do you need the full rows? replace the `*` with table1.column_name, table2.colum_name, etc, rather than fetching the lot

Comment: Ops, suddenly just working fine. Cause I change "left join" to "join", I think the system more clear about which column to explore with join table, the system will slow down due to table more focus on left table when using "left join" keyword instead

Comment: When you need help with query performance problems, please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Pay special attention to the section on query performance. Please, if you still need help, [edit] your question to provide necessary details.

Comment: `OR` is generally hard for MySQL to optimize. Also, if you're going to test `table2` columns in the `WHERE` clause, you shouldn't use `LEFT JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` is usually more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to each table:

```
INDEX(email, mobile)  -- in either order.
```

If that does not speed it up enough, then *also* turn the `OR` into a `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
     FROM ( ( SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE email = ... AND mobile = ... )
              UNION DISTINCT
            ( SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE email = ... AND mobile = ... )
          ) AS x
    JOIN table1 WHERE table1.id = x.id
    JOIN table2 WHERE table2.id = x.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD INDEX `table1_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD INDEX `table2_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD INDEX `table1_idx_email_mobile_id` (`email`, `mobile`, `id`);
ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD INDEX `table2_idx_email_mobile_id` (`email`, `mobile`, `id`);
```

And the transformed query (avoiding the OR condition, which is not indexable, by using UNION DISTINCT):

```
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table1`
        LEFT JOIN
    `table2` ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE
    ((table2.email = 'test@test.com'
        AND table2.mobile = '99999999'))) UNION DISTINCT (SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table1`
        LEFT JOIN
    `table2` ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE
    ((table1.email = 'test@test.com'
        AND table1.mobile = '99999999')))
```

P.S, if there is no option to have duplicates, use UNION ALL instead of UNION DISTINCT, as it should perform better (avoid the duplicates elimination, which can take time).